# Dynamic programming to find the maximum cost path of a 2D grid

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a 2D grid, G with q rows and p columns where each cell G[i][j] contain an integer. It need to travel from the top left (0,0) to bottom right (q-1,p-1). I can only move right and down 1 unit at a time. As I visit a cell, the amount in the cell G[i][j] is added to the total. I need to maximize total and get the path. This is my first attempt

```
def findMaxPerson1(q, p, grid, memo={}):
    key = f"{q},{p}"
    if key in memo:
        return memo[key]
    if q == 0 and p == 0:  # Start point
        return grid[0][0]
    if q < 0 or p < 0:
        return 0
    up = findMaxPerson1(q-1, p, grid, memo)  # Up
    left = findMaxPerson1(q, p-1, grid, memo)  # Left
    if up >= left:
        memo[key] = up + grid[q][p]
        return memo[key]
    else:
        memo[key] = left + grid[q][p]
        return memo[key]
```

I got 15 from above code. Now I try to modify the previous code to get also the path and the maximum total.
This is my attempt code:

```
def findMaxPerson1(q, p, grid, memo={}):
        key = f"{q},{p}"
        if key in memo:
            return memo[key]
        if q == 0 and p == 0:
            return {
                'total': grid[q][p],
                'path': [(q, p)]
            }
        if q < 0 or p < 0:
            return None
        up = findMaxPerson1(q-1, p, grid, memo)  # Up
        left = findMaxPerson1(q, p-1, grid, memo)  # Left
        if up is not None and left is not None:  # Both are dictionary
            if up['total'] >= left['total']:
                up['total'] = up['total'] + grid[q][p]
                up['path'].append((q, p))
                memo[key] = up
                return up
            else:
                left['total'] = left['total'] + grid[q][p]
                left['path'].append((q, p))
                memo[key] = left
                return left
        if up is not None:
            up['total'] = up['total'] + grid[q][p]
            up['path'].append((q, p))
            memo[key] = up
            return up
        else:
            left['total'] = left['total'] + grid[q][p]
            left['path'].append((q, p))
            memo[key] = left
                return left

    print(findMaxPerson1(2, 1, grid, {}))
```

Using this modified code with the same grid, I get this output:

```
{'total': 19, 'path': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]}
```

This is the grid I use:

```
grid = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
]
```

Why the path is not correct?
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no way we can see that the path is not correct. Can you provide the input?

Comment: The description of the problem is not clear. **"It need to travel from (0,0) to (q-1,p-1) with maximum total of the visited cell."** — why visiting all cells or walking in circles infinitely is not the answer? Are there additional constraints you didn't mention?

Comment: Your first attempt also outputs `19` which is incorrect. Also, Are you allowed only to move in 2 directions or all four? The code implies 2 but you haven't mentioned that in your problems statement.

Comment: Now your code is travelling from bottom right to top left but problem statement says from top left to bottom right.

Comment: I have edit the post and elaborate more about the problem.

Comment: @user1984 Yes this is how I approach the problem, from end to the start. I just reverse the direction. Output is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the second approach is that you're reusing and updating the same object as the value for multiple keys in `memo`.

It the first approach, the value of `memo` is a simple integer, and when you do `memo[key] = up + grid[q][p]` the value is copied. Now the value of `up` and value of `memo[key]` are completely independent of each other.

In contrast, in the second approach, you do:

```py
up['total'] = up['total'] + grid[q][p]
up['path'].append((q, p))
memo[key] = up
```

which **modifies** `up` without copying it, and now you have the same object in `up` and `memo[key]` which has the same updated value.

---

Naive way to fix the issue would be to [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) `up` and `left` before the modification, as such:

```py
import copy
...
up = copy.deepcopy(up)
left = copy.deepcopy(left)
```

This fixes the issue, now second approach prints:

```
{'total': 15, 'path': [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]}
```

But this is very inefficient, as it copies the whole path every time, making your algorithm O(n<sup>4</sup>) instead of O(n²).

The better way is to store only the previous key for each key (instead of the whole path). After the main part of the algorithm is done, you can reconstruct the path by following this backward references.